# Reset pg_stat_statements with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am using a PostgreSQL instance running in Google Cloud SQL.

I am trying to reset the pg_stat_statements because we made improvements to our tables and added some index. Unfortunately, when I try to run the following command using the main `postgres` user:

```
select pg_stat_reset();
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for function pg_stat_reset
```

I understand that it's a managed service and some things need to be walled off, but it's important to be able to reset pg_stat so you can tune the database. Basically if you make a change, you need to be able to reset pg_stat so that its output isn't polluted from data prior to the change. Even in a managed service, this kind of tuning is critical to be able to do.

Anyone know how I can get this to work with Google Cloud SQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to ask GoogleCloud Support about this and here's what they got back with:

> pg_stat_reset() needs superuser privileges. But it is not supported in
>   CloudSQL. We recommand that you use pg_stat_statements_reset()
>   function instead to reset the statistics. To do this, either user has
>   to be created from Cloud Console (i.e. Default PostgreSQL user), or
>   EXECUTE permission on this function should be granted by a default
>   PostgreSQL user by executing the following command: grant execute on
>   function pg_stat_statements_reset() to ;

I was able to use this command successfully using the postgres user. Note that this function must be run on the database where pg_stat_statement was enabled.

Comment: After running  pg_stat_statements_reset() as the default postgres user my index usage statistics didn't get reset to zero.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Altough you can't run the function you want in CloudSQL, but you can achieve the same effect by resetting individual index stats by using `pg_stat_reset_single_table_counters` function. You need to be logged in as user with `cloudsqlsuperuser` role and you can't grant EXECUTE on this function to another user. To reset all indexes for non-postgres tables run the below query:

```
select relname, pg_stat_reset_single_table_counters(oid)
from pg_class 
where reltype=0 
and relname not like 'pg_%';
```