# pg_stat_statements_reset() permission denied on Google Cloud SQL PostrgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

**Main Issue**

I'm unable to execute the function `SELECT pg_stat_statements_reset();` in order to profile changes in query optimization due to insufficient permissions.
The error message reads:
`permission denied for function pg_stat_statements_reset`

I would like to know if there are any other ways to reset the pg_stats on Cloud SQL PostgreSQL?

**Environment**

- PG version: PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4, 64-bit
- Platform: Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL
- User: default postgres user with `cloudsqlsuperuser` role

**Attempted Steps**

I have found a previous answer on this topic which suggested that `pg_stat_statements_reset()` should work from the default postgres user created through the cloud console. However, the listed solution does not work, it returns the same permission denied error

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912610/reset-pg-stat-statements-with-google-cloud-sql?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Cloud SQL supports [several modules for PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions) to extend its functionality.

One of the extensions (modules) is: [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/pgstatstatements.html). It allows tracking  execution statistics of SQL statements executed by a server. To reset statistics function pg_stat_statements_reset() is used.

Before using extension (module), it has to be installed:

1. [Connect to the PostgreSQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#cloud-shell) from Cloud Shell using default *user: postgres*

```
gcloud sql connect [INSTANCE_ID] --user=postgres
```

2. When connected to the database, [create extension pg_stat_statements](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions)

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements
```

3. Execute the function to reset statistics. **By default, It can only be executed by superusers**:

```
SELECT pg_stat_statements_reset()
```

4. (optional) Grant privilege for stats resetting to other users:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_stat_statements_reset TO xuser;
```

Comment: I ran pg_stat_statements_reset but the stats on my index usage didn't reset to zero as expected

Comment: You can reset index using pg_stat_reset() that is not supported on Cloud SQL.  [Autovaccum](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#list-flags-postgres), needs pg_stat_user_indexes to work. Maybe this article will help you understand better [usage of the indexes](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes/).

Comment: Right, so if I want stats on indexes I guess I need to snapshot them from time to time and look at the differences.

Comment: I had to remove the parentheses in the `GRANT` statement in order for it to execute properly

Answer (score 2):

With snapshots:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stat_snap_1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stat_snap_2;

-- first time
CREATE TABLE stat_snap_1 AS SELECT * FROM pg_stat_statements WHERE queryid IS NOT NULL;
-- second time
CREATE TABLE stat_snap_2 AS SELECT * FROM pg_stat_statements WHERE queryid IS NOT NULL;

SELECT s2.calls - s1.calls, s2.total_time - s1.total_time, s2.*, s1.*
FROM stat_snap_2 s2
FULL OUTER JOIN stat_snap_1 s1 ON s1.queryid = s2.queryid
ORDER BY s2.total_time - s1.total_time DESC NULLS LAST;
```